# Using javascript how to break the while loop after a set time?

Tags: javascript, loops, timer, break, imacros

I have a while loop which looks like this:

```
while(s1 != "#EANF#")
{
iimPlay("CODE:REFRESH");
iimPlay("CODE:TAG POS=1 TYPE=* ATTR=TXT:Contacted:* EXTRACT=TXT")
var s1 = iimGetLastExtract();
}
```

it will refresh the web page until it finds what it wants. However sometimes it becomes an infinite loop and I want to simply set a timer so that it would break the while loop and carry on. I tried looking at settimeout but couldn't figure out how to do it. I want this while loop to just give up refreshing the web page if it doesn't find what it wants after lets say 3 minutes.

Comment: you just can't write JS code like that.  What does `iimGetLastExtract` do?  Is it asynchronous?

Comment: What is `iimPlay`? Anyway, if you are refreshing the page, then you start running the JavaScript from the beginning, thus entering a loop.

Comment: settTimeout is the way to go. it will return a number, with this number you can cancel executions passing this to the clearTimeout function.

Comment: sorry forgot to mentione that I'm using iMacros with this javascript so essentially:

iimPlay("CODE:REFRESH"); <-----  will refresh the webpage. 

iimPlay("CODE:TAG POS=1 TYPE=* ATTR=TXT:Contacted:* EXTRACT=TXT")  <----   will look for a particular string in that webpage

var s1 = iimGetLastExtract();   <----  if it doesn't find the string then iimGetLastExtract() returns "#EANF#"

Comment: OK so... And I don't know about I macros but if it has a listener like onResultChange then u can use it other wise you should concider to two things first. The 'iimGetLastExtract();' may contain the result after 0.5 or maybe 100 seconds so you should have a loop to check  every 1second to see if it is returning a result or not and then you need to cancle that timer after 3 mins mening that its not gonna work.

Comment: This question is from 2015.  Why is it marked as a duplicate of a question in 2018?  Shouldn't it be the other way around?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

EDIT: **This may not be the correct answer**...please see comments

---

You can use a flag that is flipped after 3 minutes in your while loop condition:

```
var keepGoing = true;
setTimeout(function() {
    // this will be executed in 3 minutes
    // causing the following while loop to exit
    keepGoing = false;
}, 180000); // 3 minutes in milliseconds

while(s1 != "#EANF#" && keepGoing === true)
{
iimPlay("CODE:REFRESH");
iimPlay("CODE:TAG POS=1 TYPE=* ATTR=TXT:Contacted:* EXTRACT=TXT")
var s1 = iimGetLastExtract();
}
```

Comment: nice approach! never dawned on me

Comment: Who am I to judge but this is not the approach you should be looking for. @Lukas Morkunas

Comment: OK so... And I don't know about I macros but if it has a listener like onResultChange then u can use it other wise you should concider to two things first. The 'iimGetLastExtract();' may contain the result after 0.5 or maybe 100 seconds so you should have a loop to check every 1second to see if it is returning a result or not and then you need to cancle that timer after 3 mins mening that its not gonna work.

Comment: for some reason it gave error because of the setTimeout so I decided to work around it this way:

var count = 0;
while(s1 != "#EANF#" && count < 10)
{ 
iimPlay("CODE:REFRESH");
iimPlay("CODE:TAG POS=1 TYPE=* ATTR=TXT:Contacted:* EXTRACT=TXT")
var s1 = iimGetLastExtract();
count++
}

It'll count the number of times it loops istead of a timer which is also ok with me. Thanks for the help!

Comment: This wont work.

Comment: This doesn't work because of how javascript and the event loop works. The timeout function from setTimeout does not have a chance to ever run, because javascript is bust synchronously iterating through the while loop. You might as well save a limit timestamp and compare Date.now() with that timestamp in your loop.

Comment: @lucascaro, thanks, I'm unable to delete my answer since it was accepted, but I edited it to draw attention to the comments section

Answer (score -1):

About your question you may define a flag variable and check it in while loop and change its value in timer.

Like :

your while loop:

```
while(mflag==0){
    //codes
}
```

Your timer function

```
Function mtimer(){
    mflag=1;
}
```

And somewhere before while loop:

```
var mflag=0;
var mt= setTimeout(mtimer,3*60*1000);
```

But what I want to say is that I think you have wrong approach in refreshing webpage in a while loop. Maybe you should use Ajax or something. And I might be able to help if you give more information about whole thing you are about to do.